# Error : for: undefined (Scheme)

Tags: for-loop, scheme

I have to make a function in Scheme (R5RS) that works as follow :
(power-close-to b n)
And it has to return a integer that I call "e" that is :
b^e > n
With b, e and n integers.

So if we do :
(power-close-to 2 10) 
It has to return 4, because 4 is the first integer for which b^e > n
I've made this function in an iterative way but I have to make it in an recursive form.
So this is my code:

```
(define e 0)
(define (power-close-to b n)
  (for ((e (< (expt b e) n))
    (+ e 1))
    e))
```

But when I try it, Scheme gives following error : "for: undefined;"
So it seems my Scheme don't know the procedure "for", but I saw it in multiple Scheme codes on the internet, so I don't understand why in my case he says he don't know "for".

Thanks for your help!

EDIT : I tried making it recursive, this is how i did it, but i think it still is iterative, and i really don't have any idea how i could make it recursive.

```
(define e 0)
(define (power-close-to b n)
  (if (< (expt b e) n)
    (and (set! e (+ e 1)) (power-close-to b n)) 
    e))
```

I also tried this, but when i try it, it never prints anything and never ends (but this is recursive (i think))

```
(define e 0)
(define (power-close-to b n)
  (if (< (expt b e) n)
    (* b (power-close-to b n)) 
    e))
```

Comment: You're confounding what "iterative" and "recursive" mean. In Scheme it's common to write recursive solutions, but some of those recursive solutions behave _iteratively_, when written as tail recursions. The first implementation in the question won't work, `for` doesn't exist in your interpreter

Comment: What Scheme implementation are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When someone asks you to transform a recursive procedure in Scheme into an iterative one, it *generally* means that you have to use tail recursion, not that you should use the looping constructs of the language.

Notice that not all Scheme interpreters provide a `for` loop (most will provide a `do` loop, but I don't think that's the point of the exercise). The error you're reporting means that your interpreter doesn't have a `for` construct, so it's quite possible that you're expected to rewrite the procedure in a tail recursive fashion. I'll give you an example of what I mean, this is a recursive factorial:

```
(define (fac n)
  (if (zero? n)
      1
      (* n (fac (sub1 n)))))

(fac 10)
=> 3628800
```

Now the same procedure can be written in such a way that it generates an iterative *process* (even though syntactically, it still uses recursion):

```
(define (fac n acc) ; now the result is stored in the accumulator parameter
  (if (zero? n)     ; when recursion ends
      acc           ; return accumulator
      (fac (sub1 n) (* n acc)))) ; else update accumulator in each iteration

(fac 10 1) ; initialize the accumulator in the right value
=> 3628800
```

What's the point, you ask? that the second version of the procedure is written in tail-recursive form (notice that there's nothing left to do after the recursive call ends), so a compiler trick called [tail call optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) kicks in and the procedure runs in constant stack space, just as efficient as a loop in other non-functional languages - making recursive calls very cheap. Now try to write your `power-close-to` implementation so it uses a tail call.

Comment: Thanks for answering, in that case the function i already made was in iterative form. So now i tried making it recursive, but I have a problem. When making it recursive, like I saw it many on internet and also in your example, at the end I have to do something, like +, -, *, /   but in my case, I can't do that, because I have to encreasy "e" with 1, but e isn't a parameter of my function. So how do I can make this recursive then?

Comment: @HyperZ start passing `e` as parameter, it's a very bad idea to leave that value as a global variable, that's not the way to go. And don't use `set!`, it's not necessary to mutate the value as long as you keep passing it as parameter and updating it as parameter, just as I did with `acc` in my example

Comment: Yes, but then i have to do one of those (+,-,*,/) with my function, like u did in u'r example :  ( * n (fac (sub1 n)))))                  But my problem is that i dont have to do any of those 4 things with my  function, i only have to encrease "e" with 1, and it has to be a recursive form. So that's why I don't understand how to do it :( And i also may not introduce a third parameter.

Comment: @HyperZ to increase `e` without using `+` use the `add1` procedure. Introducing a third parameter is the cleanest way to do it, if you can't because of your teacher forbids it, well, that's too bad - it'll lead to a non-elegant answer; but there are alternatives: you can use an inner helper procedure, or a named `let`, so the outer function doesn't have to receive additional parameters. Using what I showed you above I'm sure you can write the solution, it's up to you now.

Comment: "most should provide a do loop", isn't `do` R5RS? I haven't run across a Scheme without it

Comment: @jozefg sure, standard interpreters do, but I have no idea if OP is using a teaching language that doesn't

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Fair enough, I was just curious, good answer btw, +1

Comment: @jozefg thanks :) it's a shame that OP changed the question and it's no longer relevant. OP started asking how to turn a recursion into iteration, and now is asking how to turn iteration into recursion...

Comment: Yes, but i have to do it like in Oscar Lopez's example given above :   (* n (fac (sub1 n)))))                                                 but then for my function, but i don't know how to do it because i have to increase "e" with 1 and "e" isn't a formal parameter of my function...

Comment: @HyperZ you can do this: (set! e (add1 e)) but again, that's not the idiomatic way to solve a problem in Scheme, in most cases you're not supposed to declare global variables and mutate them inside functions, that's plain wrong when simply passing the value as parameter will work

Answer (score 0):

What comes closest (and handiest) to the traditional loop is the named let (search for "named let" [here](http://www.scheme.com/tspl3/control.html)). That would look like this:

```
(define (power-close-to b n)
  (let loop ((e 0))
    (if (<= (expt b e) n)
        (loop (+ e 1))
        e)))

(display (power-close-to 2 10))
```

The loop variable is defined at the let level, so it is local to the loop (at not global as in your example). Other than that the code looks pretty similar to yours.

A named let creates an inner function, so you could also express it as follows:

```
(define (power-close-to b n)

  (define (loop e)
    (if (<= (expt b e) n)
        (loop (+ e 1))
        e))

  (loop 0))
```

Unfortunately, R5RS does not support default values for arguments, but if you want to avoid the inner function you could go for:

```
(define (power-close-to b n e)
  (if (<= (expt b e) n)
      (power-close-to b n (+ e 1))
      e))
```

but then you'd have to call it with an additional 0 like

```
(power-close-to 2 10 0)
```

Comment: U gave me two iterative forms, I also have the iterative form. But i have to make a recursive form.                                            @OscarLopez I tried using let, but then it is also iterative because I do (+ e 1) and then call my function again.

Comment: @HyperZ loop is calling itself, that's recursive.